# Changing my screen resolution?

Tags: arch-linux

I have Arch Linux without a graphical interface installed on my laptop that has a 3200x1800 resolution, so I can barely see the text. I tried the [Uvesafb](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Uvesafb) tutorial on the Arch Linux website however I get the following errors on boot

```
uvesafb: Getting VBE info block failed (eax=0x4f00, err=1)
uvesafb: vbe_init() failed with -22
```

I tried editing the `GRUB_GFXMODE=` string in my GRUB file to my desired resolution but nothing changed. I looked into the KMS method but there are no `EDID` files in my filesystem. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to have v86d installed.
Have CONFIG_FRAMEBUFFER_CONSOLE=y set in your .config.

As an info, the error can be is due to incorrectly/insufficiently supported EFI format.
I suggest you let the system work in legacy BIOS mode if you do not use something supported by EFI and not by classic BIOS. This could prevent similar problems on other categories.

Comment: I do have v86d installed and my BIOS is on legacy mode. Which .config file should I add that line to?

Comment: It must be added in the kernel configuration.

Answer (score -1):

use xrandre to change the resolution

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please take the 2-minute [tour]. 
Moreover, open [Help] and read at least [How do I write a good answer?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer). Your contribution seems to be too brief…

Comment: While this may answer the question, it would be a better answer if you could provide some explanation **why** it does so.